# Post and retrieve parameters using the exec function in PHP

Tags: php

I have been doing quite a lot of research but I haven't found a clear and simple answer to my problem.

I would simply like to execute several php scripts inside another php script (which implies using the exec function) using a variable.

The reason I want to use the exec command in particular, is that I must run the script in parallel.

I.e I have two php scripts: `a.php` and `b.php`, and I want to do something like

`a.php`

```
exec (/usr/bin/php b.php -variable = foo)
```

`b.php`

```
echo foo.
```

Comment: Try this http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/12/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using include is clean solution still if you want to do something like that

a.php

```
exec (php b.php -v=foo)
```

b.php

```
$arguments = getopt("v");
print_r($arguments);
```

getopt [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

Comment: if it helped you, you can check the answer as correct so other people can use the same.

Answer (score 0):

You said :

> I would simply like to execute a php script inside another php script(which implies using the exec function)

Read about the [include](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php) function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I forgot to specify that, as I want to run the script in parellel, (in the background), I want to use exec.